# Loaning an asset with unrealized gains

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax

Let's say I have an asset that has appreciated in value since purchasing it. Converting it to cash is subject to short term capital gains.

What happens if instead of selling the asset, it's loaned to someone else for the value of the asset and regular interest payments are made back to me until the asset is returned?

How is this taxed?

Comment: What type of asset?  Broadly, the interest income you receive would be taxed at your income tax rate which is probably equal to your short term capital gains tax rate ignoring state tax issues.  But if, say, the asset is real estate, loaning real estate to someone presumably means that you're renting it out in which case you'd be doing things like depreciating the asset for tax purposes.

Comment: The idea is, I have X amount of bitcoin which is subject to an insane amount of taxes. What if I loaned that bitcoin to a company I control in order for it to invest it in various other businesses with the expectation that 1. I would get interest only payments back and 2. it would need to be returned to me in a specified time.

Comment: OK.  So a non arms-length transaction.  What type of company (is this a pass-through entity)?  And presumably the business would sell the bitcoin in order to get cash to invest elsewhere and then owe you the bitcoin on its books?

Comment: Well originally I was considering forming a company for opportunity zone investing, and that might still be the path I go. However, as I was thought experimenting this, I remembered that when I borrowed money to buy rentals in the past, the loan I got wasn't taxed and the interest paid back was tax deductible. I wondered what the other side of the coin would be like. So yes, I would expect the company to sell the bitcoin and use it to purchase other hard assets to pay me interest back. It would be recorded as a long term liability on the company books.

Comment: It would probably be similar to a cash loan from a private investor to a business, used to purchase a thing(s)